# gumbo parser HTML5

Tags: html, c++, парсер

Здравствуйте.

Для своих целей использую библиотеку **gumbo-parser**, которую можно найти [здесь](https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser).

Проблема заключается в том, что этот парсер у меня стоит на серваке, на нем открыт сокет и все входные данные попадают на вход функции **gumbo_parse()**. Конечно же идет проверка на то, что входные данные являются HTML страничкой, но все же я никак не могу понять, как определить, что парсер сработал и не произошло там никаких внутренних ошибок?

Например, я попробовал подать на вход обычный JavaScript, вот так выглядит код:

```
GumboOutput* output = gumbo_parse(&buffer[0]);
assert(output->errors.length == 0);
const GumboError *error = (const GumboError *)output->errors.data[0];
assert(error->type == GUMBO_ERR_PARSER);
assert(error->v.parser.input_type == GUMBO_TOKEN_DOCTYPE);
assert(error->position.offset == 0);

std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
```

И вот что странно, так это то, что все замечательно проходит и программа не крашится. Если кто пользовался, скажите как определить, что **gumbo_parse()** не сработал или что входные данные неверные ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С точки зрения парсера, javascript код - это обычный текст. И преобразуется в текстовую ноду.

В gumbo parser нет валидатора html.

Comment: Да, спасибо, теперь понял. А не знаете случаем как получить название ноды, как строки? Или только сравнением выяснять?

Comment: Название ноды? Вы имеете ввиду название тега? (A, DIV, BR)
Или GumboNodeType? (GUMBO_NODE_DOCUMENT, GUMBO_NODE_ELEMENT...)

Comment: Да, название тега

Comment: @Виталий `gumbo_normalized_tagname(node->v.element.tag);`

Comment: А где-нибудь можно нормальную документацию достать ?

Comment: @Виталий изучайте код оберток https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser#external-bindings-and-other-wrappers , я вообще использую gumbo-query

Comment: Да я тоже себе его установил и собрал .lib, но некоторых вещей я там добиться не могу, приходится "вручную". А можно ли как-нибудь GumboOutput обратно в char* превратить ? Например задача в том, что надо удалить некорректные ноды и обратно это все сохранить.

Comment: @Виталий 
 Насколько я знаю gumbo такого не умеет. Это, можно сказать, парсер выполняющий только одностороннее преобразование. Можно вручную сериализовать дерево нодов. Мы уже обсуждали это с автором обертки
https://github.com/lazytiger/gumbo-query/issues/10
Он добавил функции startPos и endPos, но насколько я понимаю, это  позиция в ИСХОДНОМ нераспарсенном тексте.